Violation of the identification of factor model below Ledermann bound
In Bekker and ten Berge, 1997, it is said that the variance of independent error $\Sigma$ is almost surely uniquely identified when the number of factor is below ledermann bound.
In part3 of the proof of this theorem, they used the following

I wonder in what case the jacobian matrix does not have full row rank?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
